# Storing Markdown in a Yesod Persist Model

Tags: haskell, markdown, yesod, persist

I am trying to store markdown in a field on a Persistent model with a MySQL backend. I've broken the use case down to:

models:

```
TestModel
    content Markdown
```

Model.hs:

```
import Text.Markdown (Markdown)
import Yesod.Text.Markdown ()
....
```

This seems to create the correct migrations:

```
mysql> show columns in test_model;
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| content | text       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

However when I try to retrieve data from this table, I'm presented with an exception. The example below is from a `cabal repl` but the same happens when the application is running:

```
repl> testid <- db $ insert $ TestModel $ Markdown "# Hello world"
[Debug#SQL] INSERT INTO `test_model`(`content`) VALUES(?); [PersistText "# Hello world"]
repl> testmodel <- db $ get testid
[Debug#SQL] SELECT `content` FROM `test_model` WHERE `id`=?; [PersistInt64 2]
*** Exception: runFakeHandler issue: InternalError "get TestModelKey {unTestModelKey = SqlBackendKey {unSqlBackendKey = 2}}: field content: Not a PersistText value"
```

My first guess was that the value for the TestModel constructor was wrong, but the same error occurs even when creating the object using a `markdownField` in a form:

```
testModelForm :: AForm Handler TestModel
testModelForm = TestModel
        <$> areq markdownField "Content" Nothing

getTestModelR :: TestModelId -> Handler Html
getTestModelR testModelId = do
    testmodel <- runDB $ get404 testModelId
....
08/Aug/2015:12:44:33 -0700 [Error#yesod-core] get TestModelKey {unTestModelKey = SqlBackendKey {unSqlBackendKey = 2}}: field content: Not a PersistText value @(yesod-core-1.4.12:Yesod.Core.Class.Yesod ./Yesod/Core/Class/Yesod.hs:577:5)
```

Has anybody seen this exception before and know how to handle it? The only documentation of this error I could seem to find was the [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-text-markdown-0.1.8/docs/src/Yesod-Text-Markdown.html) for `yesod-text-markdown`.

Comment: why not store markdown simply as Text ? then u can use a library to convert markdown Text to html, that works for me

Comment: I think I'll try that approach, but if the field is type `Text`, how would I be able to validate input for that field against the `Markdown` type? I can use `markdownField` from `Yesod.Text.Markdown` but that doesn't seem to work when the field is type `Text`.

Comment: This question seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31902061/what-does-not-a-persisttext-value-mean

Comment: This looks to be a real issue with either yesod-text-markdown or persistent (I can reproduce it). The error message stems from here: https://github.com/Tarrasch/yesod-text-markdown/blob/7d7e35b97d50360197a6139df8354d9926ede8a8/Yesod/Text/Markdown.hs#L22-L25

Comment: Ok, persist-text-markdown is expecting `PersistText` but it's getting `PersistByteString`. Perhaps it should support deserializing from both of those? I'll investigate.

Comment: I started an issue about this: https://github.com/Tarrasch/yesod-text-markdown/issues/12

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be caused by a bug in the `persistent-mysql` package that's now fixed in `persistent-mysql-2.3`.

Here's the root cause for those interested:

The MySQL C library (and by extension the Haskell `mysql` package, which `persistent-mysql` depends on) doesn't distinguish between binary and textual data at the type level. So if you saved a `TEXT` value to the database, when it was looked it up by persistent it appeared to be binary data (a `PersistByteString`).

I fixed this in [#451](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/pull/451) by checking the character set of the column, which the MySQL API docs recommend as the appropriate solution.

For more details, see that pull request or [this issue](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/issues/448).

Thanks for asking this question; I wouldn't have realized there was a bug otherwise.