# what does "Not a PersistText value" mean?

Tags: mysql, haskell, mariadb, yesod

I'm new to yesod and I'm trying to make the same blog project from this screencast: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SadfV-qbVg8 with the only difference being that I'm using MariaDB instead of PostgreSQL. Every time I add a new blog post and redirect to the page that shows it I see this error:

```
[Error#yesod-core] get BlogPostKey {unBlogPostKey = SqlBackendKey {unSqlBackendKey = 5}}: field article: Not a PersistText value @(yesod-core-1.4.12:Yesod.Core.Class.Yesod ./Yesod/Core/Class/Yesod.hs:577:5)
```

What exactly does that mean? If I look into the database, it has all the posts stored correctly. Why does it fail to load the posts from the database?

Here's the code

model

```
User
    ident Text
    password Text Maybe
    UniqueUser ident
    deriving Typeable
Email
    email Text
    user UserId Maybe
    verkey Text Maybe
    UniqueEmail email

BlogPost
    title Text
    article Markdown
```

PostDetails.hs (Gets the post from DB and shows it)

```
module Handler.PostDetails where

import Import

getPostDetailsR :: BlogPostId -> Handler Html
getPostDetailsR blogPostId = do     
    blogPost <- runDB $ get404 blogPostId 
    defaultLayout $ do
    $(widgetFile "postDetails/post")
```

PostNew.hs (Creates a new post and stores it in the DB, after insertion, it redirects to PostDetails.hs with the new post)

```
module Handler.PostNew where

import Import
import Yesod.Form.Bootstrap3
import Yesod.Text.Markdown

blogPostForm :: AForm Handler BlogPost
blogPostForm = BlogPost 
            <$> areq textField (bfs ("Title" :: Text)) Nothing
            <*> areq markdownField (bfs ("Article" :: Text)) Nothing

getPostNewR :: Handler Html
getPostNewR = do
    (widget, enctype) <- generateFormPost $ renderBootstrap3 BootstrapBasicForm blogPostForm
    defaultLayout $ do
        $(widgetFile "posts/new")

postPostNewR :: Handler Html
postPostNewR = do
    ((res, widget), enctype) <- runFormPost $ renderBootstrap3 BootstrapBasicForm blogPostForm
    case res of
     FormSuccess blogPost -> do
        blogPostId <- runDB $ insert blogPost
        redirect $ PostDetailsR blogPostId
     _ -> defaultLayout $(widgetFile "posts/new")
```

I don't understand why the compiler doesn't catch this error. When I create a post, instead of the title I se "Internal Server Error"

Comment: `PersistText` is a constructor of the [`PersistValue` data type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-0.5.1/docs/Database-Persist-Base.html#t:PersistValue)

Comment: You should add the appropriate code to the question. It is hard for others to see a video for helping you out.

Comment: can u add the code database entity definition and database-relevant code?BTW,sqlite needs zero configuation and is easier to use

Comment: Hi @gesuwall, I made the screencast you're watching. Your code looks correct to me; would you mind putting your code on Github so I can try to reproduce? It might be a MariaDB-related thing; I'll try that out.

Comment: This question seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31898691/storing-markdown-in-a-yesod-persist-model

Comment: This looks to be a real issue with either yesod-text-markdown or persistent. The error message stems from here: https://github.com/Tarrasch/yesod-text-markdown/blob/7d7e35b97d50360197a6139df8354d9926ede8a8/Yesod/Text/Markdown.hs#L22-L25

Comment: I made a repo with the full source code. Since I didn't understand what was going on I removed markdown. so First commit has no Markdown and works great. Second commit has markdown again, and every Blog post shows this PersistText Value error. https://github.com/GAumala/MyBlog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be caused by a bug in the `persistent-mysql` package that's now fixed in `persistent-mysql-2.3`.

Here's the root cause for those interested:

The MySQL C library (and by extension the Haskell `mysql` package, which `persistent-mysql` depends on) doesn't distinguish between binary and textual data at the type level. So if you saved a `TEXT` value to the database, when it was looked it up by persistent it appeared to be binary data (a `PersistByteString`).

This was fixed in [#451](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/pull/451) by checking the character set of the column, which the MySQL API docs recommend as the appropriate solution.

For more details, see that pull request or [this issue](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/issues/448).

Thanks for asking this question; I wouldn't have realized there was a bug otherwise.